# Can I make a Netbeans "empty file" part of compiled jar file?

Tags: java, netbeans, java.util.scanner

I have 80,000 words for a crossword (among others) puzzle word pattern matcher. (User inputs "ba??" and gets, among other things, "ball, baby, bank, ..." or enters "ba*" and gets the aforementioned as well as "bat, basket, babboon...".)

I stuck the words in a Netbeans "empty file" and named it "dictionary". The file's contents are just (80,000) words, one per line. This code works like a charm to read the dictionary (code that filters is omitted):

```
  static void showMatches(String pattern, String legal, String w) throws IOException
  {
    Path p = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Dov\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Masterwords\\src\\masterwords\\dictionary");

    String word;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(p).useDelimiter("\r"); 

      while(sc.hasNext()){ 

          word = sc.next().substring(1);
          gui.appendOutput(word);
      }

    sc.reset();
  }
```

**Is there a way to make the file (named "dictionary") become part of the compiled jar file so that I only need to "ship" one file to new, (largely helpless) users?**

In another matter of curiosity...

**Is it possible to make the argument to Paths.get(...) something like "masterwords/src/dictionary" to make the connection for the Scanner object to be able read it?** I'm wondering if this might relate to an answer my first question. (If there's a way, I can't stumble onto it. Whatever similar string I use, I get no error, no output, no "build successful"--gotta click Run > Stop build/run.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain, based on your description, that my solution addresses your issue, but let me restate the problem as I understand it: You have a .jar file that relies on a dictionary resource. That resource is subject to change, and you'd like to be able to update it without having to ship out a whole new .jar containing a new dictionary.

If I'm reading you correctly, you want something like:

```
private File getInstallPath()
{
    return new File(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
}
```

This will return the install directory of your .jar file, which is where you can put your dictionary resource so that the .jar knows where to find it. Of course, now you have a bit of a training issue, because users can move, delete or misplace your dictionary file.

Part II:

Now that you've clarified your question, let me again restate: You want to be able to read an arbitrary file included in your .jar file. Fine. You're probably trying to open the file as a file, but once the file is in your .jar, you need to treat it as a resource.

Try using:

```
Class myClass = Class.forName("MyClass");
ClassLoader myLoader = myclass.getClassLoader();
InputStream myStream = myLoader.getResourceAsStream(myFile);
```

Do you really need me to explain what "myClass," "myLoader," etc. refer to? Hint: "myClass" is whatever your class is that needs to read the file.

Comment: What's `MyClass`? What I REALLY want to do is have the 'dictionary' included IN the .jar file, to be executed as is, without unzipping or any other user action. Just click the email attachment "whatever.jar" and program runs, spewing words upon request.

Comment: Yeah, I _really_ needed that explanation. Do you need me to explain what 57 reputation points implies?

Comment: Just a reminder: you're here asking for free help. You provide no compensation whatsoever to the people who are answering your questions. The least you could do is drop the attitude and quit being such a bell end. If you're frustrated, the last person you should take your frustrations out on is the person helping you. Reputation points has nothing to do with understanding basic conventions.

Comment: ...class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()... was far from what I'd expected to see; I'd  not seen those methods before. I should've omitted that kneejerk reaction and started with "What I REALLY want ...". Yes I am REALLY frustrated. And I apologize for showing it. But just a reminder: you're providing help for people of widely varying levels of expertise, so either don't bother with an attitude-affected reply such as "Do you really need me to explain..." or provide the obviously needed help, ideally in the matter-of-fact manner of an experienced, patient teacher.

Comment: With all due respect, I made a plain, emotionally unladen statement. Your reaction was based on your own interpretation and emotional state and had nothing to do with my intention. When in doubt, you should ask, rather than accuse. It's what I did in asking you if you needed an explanation -- you should have done likewise. Next time, deal with the issue, not the emotion, or don't deal at all.

Comment: With all due respect, writing "Do you really need" an explanation did not amount to "asking if" I needed it since it was immediately forthcoming. It _may_ have been emotionally unladen but whether the actual intent was condescension, The Reasonable Man-On-The-Street would _interpret_ it that way. Just something to consider for your future writings. Words have meaning but also have undeniable implication. A bit of introspection could be in order, viz.: "What Stack Overflow should not be: <<...>> If you need this level of instruction, perhaps it's time to consider making a change."

Comment: I wish I could delete my comments. I apologize, Mars. I've been overly-defensive and nearly paranoid over this. If you look back at one of my first help threads I was overjoyed at and appreciated a poster for just giving a hint since I didn't want a "do-this" solution. I'm just so discouraged because I've been a very good programmer for many, many years and Java/objects are kicking my butt.

Answer (score 0):

After leaving this thread in frustration for a couple of weeks, yesterday I found a similar question at this forum, which led me to Google "java resource files" and visit [((this URL))](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html).

Between the two I figured out how to read a file named 'dictionary' that was created as a Netbeans "empty Java file", which was located in *Source Packages ... [default package]* (as shown in Netbeans Projects window) and stored as *C:\Users\Dov\!Docs\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WordPatternHelp\src\dictionary*:

```
File file = new File("src/dictionary");
```

...

```
p = file.toPath();
sc = new Scanner(p).useDelimiter("\r");
```

Success. Hooray.

But after compiling and executing the .jar file from a DOS command line, 'dictionary' couldn't be found. So the above only works from within Netbeans IDE.

After mostly erroneous attempts caused by the above 'success', I finally got success using @Mars' second suggestion like so:

```
package masterwords;
public class Masterwords
```

...

```
InputStream myStream =  Class.forName("masterwords.Masterwords").
    getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("dictionary");

sc = new Scanner(myStream).useDelimiter("\r");   // NULL PTR EXCEPTION HERE
```

So, for whatever it might be worth, a very belated thanks (and another apology) to @Mars. It was as straightforward as he indicated. Wish I'd tried it 2 weeks ago, but I'd never seen any of the methods and didn't want to take the time to learn how they work back then with other more pressing issues at hand. So I had no idea Mars had actually written the exact code I needed (except for the string arguments). Boy, do I know how the methods work now.